# Edit ribbon gone when trying to edit SharePoint 2013 list item

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, attachments

I have a list in SP that has been working fine. I am the admin and have complete full control to the whole site.

When a user that has been given "Edit" permissions to this specific list clicks on the column name that I have linked to the item, the Edit ribbon is completely gone (The ribbon that shows "Edit Item", "Version History", "Shared With", "Delete Item" etc.)

When logged in as myself, I see this ribbon, but when the user who has edit permissions for this list is logged in, they do not.

I have added the "Edit" column to the list to see if they will be able to edit the item. And this column does allow them to edit the item. Yet the ribbon is still missing.

One of the biggest reasons I need this ribbon is so users can add attachments to already created items.

Anything you can do to help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any specific masterpage applied for that site? Also is it SharePoint Online or On-Premise?

Comment: SharePoint is on-premise. There is a masterpage applied to all pages.

Comment: What makes this a little interesting is that when I set the permissions for the "Edit" group to "Design" they are then able to add attachments. But I do not want them to have "Design" capabilities because it gives them more design capabilities to the site than I am comfortable with. If I create a unique permission level and give them all rights for List Permissions, they are still unable to add attachments. But if I add the permission called "Add and Customize Pages" they can then add attachments, but it gives them rights to edit pages, which I don't want them to have. Any ideas?